Sole proprietorship business name and personal info privacy
I'm going to start selling things online (mostly just uploading designs to POD places), and in order to avoid putting my SSN into half a dozen sites, I want to get an EIN. I know that I can get one free from the IRS for a sole proprietorship, and that the name of the business will be my full name.
My question is, since my name would be the business name, do I need to publicly display it on any storefront I set up? Or does it just need to be on file in the backend of the site, along with my EIN?
For example: say I make a Redbubble page. Can I name it whatever I want, as long as Redbubble has my EIN and name in the non-public facing info for it, or do I still need to list my name somewhere publicly on the page since it's the business name associated with the EIN being used for the Redbubble store?
I wouldn't consider my real name quite as sensitive of info as my SSN, but I'd still rather not have to dox myself just to make some money online.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question, DBA rules vary from place to place and you need to check the requirements in the jurisdictions relevant to your business.

Advance warning:  Check with your county clerk to see if you need to file a Certificate As Doing Business under the company name. Without that you may be unable to open a company bank account or accept payments made out to the company. There may be other implications; IANAL.
